# Naming Convention For Images in XCode 5

Tags: ios, ipad

i am using XCode 5 when i am naming the images like that :

fbicon~ipad.png
fbicon~ipad@2x.png

Xib is getting the image

but when i am using this Convention

although tha naming convention is
fbicon~ipad.png
fbicon@2x~ipad.png

xib is not picking the images in that case.

Dont Know Why?

Comment: Do you have a question ?

Comment: i am not able to add images for ipad with the conventional naming convention.You have any idea for xcode 5?

Comment: have you run the app?

Comment: Xib is not picking the images for ipad if i used right naming convention.

Answer (score 4):

Migrate to use the assets catalogue. You just drag your images into the image wells and interface builder picks them up.

If the catalogue doesn't show the iPad iphone specific wells, open up the properties right side bar and tick the appropriate boxes.

[assets catalogue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)

Comment: thanks for the great tip ! When using device specific assets, is it still necessary or recommended to use the @2x, ~iphone and ~ipad modifiers for the filenames? 2nd question : are modifiers ~iphone and ~ipad, or -iphone and -ipad?

Comment: You don't have to, no, but if you do, it makes importing into the assets catalogue easier.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening since you are using XIB.
When used with XIB, for images to be used on iPhone one must use the convention "image~iphone" and for iPad you have to use "image~ipad". @2x is automatically appended based on which version (retina/non-retina) of the image is needed. That's why the first convention works for you.

In case of getting images from the code, e.g. if you have following versions of the "image"-

```
image~iphone.png
image~ipad.png
image@2x~iphone.png
image@2x~ipad.png
```

You just call-

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]
```

In this case, the second convention that you mentioned works- as detailed in the Apple doc-
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html
So, nothing really wrong here as I see. For XIBs, the first convention is correct. For using with code, second convention is correct.

Comment: You should add extension in imageNamed : [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]

Comment: @Francescu That's not necessary for iOS>=4.0. See the following Apple documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:

Comment: it's for that I said you should not you must. For readability I think the best practice is to specify the extension (event in the link you provided in your answer Apple specified the .PNG). But it's a dev choice I agree and upvote your answer :)